# Create new DataFrame column base on other column's search result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe as below with a datetime and a price. I would like to create a new column "lowest price" that checks the lowest price of past 5 minutes and return the price value. Is there a way to do it?

Input :

```
DateTime            Price
23/11/2021 23:59    57540.60
23/11/2021 23:58    57560.96
23/11/2021 23:57    57581.44
23/11/2021 23:56    57617.08
23/11/2021 23:55    57710.88
23/11/2021 23:54    57654.52
23/11/2021 23:53    57635.68
23/11/2021 23:52    57644.85
23/11/2021 23:51    57626.73
```

Expected Output :

```
DateTime            Price         Lowest Price (Past 5 min)
23/11/2021 23:59    57640.60      57560.96
23/11/2021 23:58    57560.96      57560.96
23/11/2021 23:57    57581.44      57581.44
23/11/2021 23:56    57617.08      57554.52
23/11/2021 23:55    57710.88      .
23/11/2021 23:54    57554.52      .
23/11/2021 23:53    57635.68      .
23/11/2021 23:52    57644.85
23/11/2021 23:51    57626.73
```

Comment: Were you after `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])).rolling('5T').min()`

Comment: What @wwnde said looks like the solution. I guess you would have to reverse the df df[::-1] and than do it again when the calculation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
df.set_index('DateTime').rolling(5).min().shift(-4).reset_index().add_suffix(' min')
```

if you want to look more than 5 rows, adjust the rolling accordingly. `rolling(n)` and `shift(n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to resolve the issue.

```
price_df_min=price_df.set_index('DateTime').rolling(5).min().shift(-4).reset_index().add_suffix(' min')
```